# What's the best way to manage ancillary data in a repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I've run into this problem on several projects, but I still don't know of an elegant solution. Here's the problem:

In a repository, in addition to the source code, there are a lot of ancillary files needed to run the code. The individual files are not necessarily large (so I'm not sure git LFS is the right answer), but they add up to many gigabytes. Much more than you want in a repo. The files might be binary file, and don't change like source code, so they don't really need to be "tracked" like source code. Currently, I just have things not checked in, but it's becoming a pain to personally keep track of all the things *not* in the repo, and move them around anytime the repo is cloned somewhere.

How do other project deal with this issue? Git LFS sounds like it was intended to solve a different problem, but can it be used to solve this one as well?

Thanks!

edit: Also, lets say you get get new ancillary data on a daily basis, for example, past weather data that your code needs to do any computation on that day, so the total collection of ancillary data slowly and steadily grows.

edit2: Another condition: If Git LFS is the solution, suppose my repo is on a company Stash server that hasn't been updated to support Git LFS, and a ticket to IT asking to upgrade to BitBucket has sat idle for months (completely hypothetical of course). Do I have other options besides Git LFS?

Comment: Control question: If you check out a commit from your repository from October 2017, assuming the project existed then but let's assume it did, do you want these ancillary data files from that date as well, or do you want to keep the current version from today?

Comment: What is your concern here? Is it the size of the repo? If these files are required, it seems you do actually want these in your repo. Looking at the LFS description, it sounds like it is exactly designed for your situation, assuming that you can put these files on a remote server where the repo can link to them. Better clarifying your concerns and why LFS isn't elegant for this might help with a solution.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, this isn't a concern I run into, but if I did, I imagine I would want to be able to run the old code from Oct 2017 on recent weather data (going with the weather example), and so I would want the ancillary weather data taken after Oct 2017.

Comment: @UncleCarl, Yes, the concern is the size of the repo. Imagine the directory that holds the code base and all libraries is 3-4GB, and the ancillary data is 10GB. Or 100GB. Is it reasonable to lug this around? I thought the reason Git LFS exists was because files greater than 1GB (or whatever the limit is) can't be checked in to Git, but individual file size is not the problem. Am I wrong? Does Git LFS work for people with this problem?

Comment: @Ryan "past weather data that your code needs to do any computation on that day", where do you calculate with the past data? Is it possible to calculate in your local git repo without pushing ancillary data  to remote repo? And does the ancillary data be lost efficacy with time goes on (such as ancillary data  before than 30 days can be deleted)?